# linking problem tinylibxml C++ Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, tinyxml

I am getting error when I try to execute the simple tinylibxml program.

OS -> Ubuntu
IDE -> e
I have download libtinyxml through apt-get install
and included the header in my program
But  I am still getting error
Sample code is pasted below

```
#include "tinyxml.h"
#define TIXML_USE_STL
#include <tinyxml.h>
void dump_to_stdout(const char* pFilename);

int main()
{
 dump_to_stdout("example1.xml");
 return 0;
}

void dump_to_stdout(const char* pFilename)
{
 TiXmlDocument doc(pFilename);
 bool loadOkay = doc.LoadFile();
 if (loadOkay)
 {
  printf("\n%s:\b", pFilename);
 }
 else
 {
  printf("Failed to load file \"%s\"\n", pFilename);
 }
}
```

As, I did googling, I found that I need to include libtinyxml.cpp and some more files.
Could you guys , please guide me how to do that.

Thanks

Comment: It will be useful if you add the error messages as well. Please also use the format code button below when adding code. It does make it more readable.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when building you will need to do something like

`g++ -c mycode.cpp` (assuming your source file is mycode.cpp)

this should generate mycode.o

you now need to do:

`g++ -o mycode -ltinyxml mycode.o`

which is the linking step. This will combine your compiled source file with the tinyxml library to produce a final executable binary mycode.

For simple stuff you can compile and link in one step but for more complex stuff you need to separate the steps out.

All this can be automated using a `make` and a `Makefile`

Take a look at [The GCC Manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.1/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html#Invoking-GCC) for more info on compiler options.

Comment: Thanks guys for such a quick and helpful response.

Comment: The problem was that I was not linking libtinyxml.a file. This file resides in my /usr/lib. I need following step g++ TinyTest.cpp /usr/lib/libtinyxml.a ....... and it works.                                                                     Simiarily , I tried in eclipse by going into project->properties->GCC C++Linker->Libraries and add tinyxml in -l  AND /usr/lib in -L /usr/lib

Comment: the -l flag that I mentioned should achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

There is a makefile that comes with tinyxml, run that to build the library and then include that library in your link line.

EDIT: and @doron has kindly provided you the instructions for "linking the library" :)